# Reading into two variables at a same time with reduce()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to reduce the complexity of the following function with `reduce()`, since the functionality is almost similar for the two variables, `selectedEnrolled` and `selectedNotEnrolled`.

I tried using `map()`, but here I am not returning anything so that just ended up having side effects which I realized is as a bad coding practice.

```
countSelectNotEnrolled(selected: any) {
  this.selectedNotEnrolled = selected.reduce((count, id) => {
    return this.hasSteps(id)
      ? count + (this.userShelf.courseIds.indexOf(id) === -1 ? 1 : 0)
      : count;
  }, 0);
  this.selectedEnrolled = selected.reduce((count, id) => {
    return this.hasSteps(id)
      ? count + (this.userShelf.courseIds.indexOf(id) === -1 ? 0 : 1)
      : count;
  }, 0);
}
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You can probably just compute this.selectedNotEnrolled = this.selected.length - this.selectedEnrolled.

Comment: @zeppelin after applying the `this.hasSteps` filter though

Comment: @nem035, yep, but you can just apply it once, and compute the other variable

Comment: @zeppelin exactly what I did as the last example in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The only difference appears to be what you're returning as the increment, depending if the current id is part of the `this.userShelf.courseIds` array.

```
countSelectNotEnrolled(selected: any) {
  this.selectedNotEnrolled = selected.reduce((count, id) => {
    return this.hasSteps(id)
      ? count + (this.userShelf.courseIds.indexOf(id) === -1 ? 1 : 0)
      //                                                       ^^^^^
      : count;
  }, 0);
  this.selectedEnrolled = selected.reduce((count, id) => {
    return this.hasSteps(id)
      ? count + (this.userShelf.courseIds.indexOf(id) === -1 ? 0 : 1)
      //                                                       ^^^^^
      : count;
  }, 0);
}
```

One approach, that is more generally applicable to refactoring patterns, is to extract that difference as a dynamic part when creating the function.

You can create a function that returns another function and accepts this increment value as the argument. Then you can use that function to create two functions, one summing the count for `selectedNotEnrolled` and the other summing for `selectedEnrolled`.

*Note: using [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is a bit cleaner than [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) when checking existence in an array.*

```
function createEnrolmentSum( // the wrapper function accepts the dynamic setup logic
  incrementIfSelected,
  incrementIfUnselected = incrementIfSelected === 1 ? 0 : 1
) {
  return function (selected) { // <--- return a function that does the common logic
    return selected.reduce((count, id) => {
      return this.hasSteps(id)
        ? count +
            (this.userShelf.courseIds.includes(id) // <-- using includes is a bit cleaner
              ? incrementIfSelected
              : incrementIfUnselected)
        : count;
    }, 0);
  };
}

// ...

// create instance methods so we maintain proper `this` behavior
getEnrolledSum = createEnrolmentSum(1); 
getNotEnrolledSum = createEnrolmentSum(0);

countSelectNotEnrolled(selected: any) {
  this.selectedNotEnrolled = this.getNotEnrolledSum();
  this.selectedEnrolled = this.getEnrolledSum();
}
```

Above is just a generic demonstration of how any similar code could get refactored. Arguably, this particular api is not very readable:

```
// this api isn't very readable because it's not clear
// what `1` or `0` mean as arguments
getEnrolledSum = createEnrolmentSum(1);
getNotEnrolledSum = createEnrolmentSum(0);
```

You could improve this readability with a config object:

```
getEnrolledSum = createEnrolmentSum({
  incrementIfSelected: 1,
  incrementIfUnselected: 0
});
getNotEnrolledSum = createEnrolmentSum({
  incrementIfSelected: 0,
  incrementIfUnselected: 1
});
```

But this doesn't improve things much because the code, although [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), is definitely complex.

I would suggest that, for your particular situation, the obvious starting solution is to compute both sums in a single loop. This won't require much complexity and will be faster since you'll run through the `selected` array only once instead of twice.

```
countSelectNotEnrolled(selected) {
  let selectedNotEnrolled = 0,
      selectedEnrolled = 0;

  for (const id of selected) {
    if (this.hasSteps(id)) {
      if (this.userShelf.courseIds.includes(id)) {
        selectedEnrolled += 1;
      } else {
        selectedNotEnrolled += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  this.selectedNotEnrolled = selectedNotEnrolled;
  this.selectedEnrolled = selectedEnrolled;
}
```

If you do want to use array reduction, you can use an object to carry the two variables through iteration loops:

```
countSelectNotEnrolled(selected) {
  const { selectedNotEnrolled, selectedEnrolled } = selected.reduce(
    (result, id) => {
      if (this.hasSteps(id)) {
        if (this.userShelf.courseIds.includes(id)) {
          result.selectedEnrolled += 1;
        } else {
          result.selectedNotEnrolled += 1;
        }
      }
      return result;
    },
    { selectedNotEnrolled: 0, selectedEnrolled: 0 } // <-- reduction result contains both variables
  );

  this.selectedNotEnrolled = selectedNotEnrolled;
  this.selectedEnrolled = selectedEnrolled;
}
```

To remove some of the nesting, we can first filter out all ids that do not have steps:

```
countSelectNotEnrolled(selected) {
  const { selectedNotEnrolled, selectedEnrolled } = selected
    .filter(this.hasSteps) // <-- apply the filter first
    .reduce(
      (result, id) => {
        if (this.userShelf.courseIds.includes(id)) {
          result.selectedEnrolled += 1;
        } else {
          result.selectedNotEnrolled += 1;
        }
        return result;
      },
      { selectedNotEnrolled: 0, selectedEnrolled: 0 }
    );

  this.selectedNotEnrolled = selectedNotEnrolled;
  this.selectedEnrolled = selectedEnrolled;
}
```

If you've already initialized the necessary variables on your instance and updating instance data has no major performance penalties, you could also just assign values to it directly:

```
countSelectNotEnrolled(selected) {
  // setup
  this.selectedEnrolled = 0;
  this.selectedNotEnrolled = 0;

  // sum
  selected
    .filter(this.hasSteps)
    .forEach(id => {
      if (this.userShelf.courseIds.includes(id)) {
        this.selectedEnrolled += 1;
      } else {
        this.selectedNotEnrolled += 1;
      }
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you could leverage filtering to split into ids belonging to enrolled and not enrolled and just extract the length:

```
countSelectNotEnrolled(selected) {
  const selectedWithSteps = selected.filter(this.hasSteps);

  this.selectedNotEnrolled = selectedWithSteps.filter(
    id => !this.userShelf.courseIds.includes(id)
  ).length;

  this.selectedEnrolled = selectedWithSteps.filter(id =>
    this.userShelf.courseIds.includes(id)
  ).length;
}
```

In fact, no need to filter twice, we can express enrolled and not enrolled in terms of each other:

```
countSelectNotEnrolled(selected) {
  const selectedWithSteps = selected.filter(this.hasSteps);

  this.selectedNotEnrolled = selectedWithSteps.filter(
    id => !this.userShelf.courseIds.includes(id)
  ).length;

  this.selectedEnrolled = selectedWithSteps.length - this.selectedNotEnrolled;
}
```

---

Overall, the best refactoring advice I would give is to worry less about specific patterns and more about code readability. We are writing in these high-level languages such as JavaScript so that humans can read it, machines don't care, they can read binary just fine. We should write code that takes the least amount of human cognitive effort to understand